# "SunX509 TrustManagerFactory not available" on AIX (SSL webservice client)

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, aix, x509

My Java component within an JBoss 4.2.2 container tries to access an SSL webservice, but it gets an exception (not critical, functionality works, response is retrieved from the ssl webservice).

OS: AIX

Java:

```
> /usr/java6_64/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap6460sr9fp1-20110208_03(SR9 FP1))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 AIX ppc64-64 jvmap6460sr9-20110203_74623 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20110203_074623
JIT  - r9_20101028_17488ifx3
GC   - 20101027_AA)
JCL  - 20110203_01
```

Code:

```
SOAPMessage reply = connection.call(message, webserviceUrl);
```

connection is a SOAPConnection.

I get the following log output:

```
2012-03-29 15:10:17,651 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker] (Thread-17) Error creating SSL Socket Factory for client invoker.
java.io.IOException: Error initializing socket factory SSL context: SunX509 TrustManagerFactory not available
        at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:230)
        at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.java:11)
        at org.jboss.remoting.security.SSLSocketBuilder.loadTrustManagers(SSLSocketBuilder.java:1407)
        at org.jboss.remoting.security.SSLSocketBuilder.initializeSocketFactorySSLContext(SSLSocketBuilder.java:1326)
        at org.jboss.remoting.security.SSLSocketBuilder.createCustomSocketFactory(SSLSocketBuilder.java:451)
        at org.jboss.remoting.security.SSLSocketBuilder.createSSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketBuilder.java:431)
        at org.jboss.remoting.security.SSLSocketBuilder.createSSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketBuilder.java:381)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.ssl.HTTPSClientInvoker.createSocketFactory(HTTPSClientInvoker.java:140)
        at org.jboss.remoting.RemoteClientInvoker.<init>(RemoteClientInvoker.java:46)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.<init>(HTTPClientInvoker.java:105)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.https.TransportClientFactory.createClientInvoker(TransportClientFactory.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.jboss.remoting.InvokerRegistry.loadClientInvoker(InvokerRegistry.java:419)
        at org.jboss.remoting.InvokerRegistry.createClientInvoker(InvokerRegistry.java:320)
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.connect(Client.java:459)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.client.RemotingConnectionImpl.createRemotingClient(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:247)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.client.RemotingConnectionImpl.invoke(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:165)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.client.SOAPRemotingConnection.invoke(SOAPRemotingConnection.java:77)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPConnectionImpl.callInternal(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:106)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:66)
        at xxx.yyy.fooservice.FooServiceImpl.foo(FooServiceImpl.java:103)
        at xxx.yyy.fooservice.FooAsyncRunner.run(FooAsyncRunner.java:31)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
```

I've tried using hints on the net to modify ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm and ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security, but error prevails.

Extra info: The exception above appeared after having specified

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=foo"
```

... in JBoss 4.2.2 startup, before that I got the following exception:

```
2012-03-28 12:10:13,424 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker] (Thread-13) Error creating SSL Socket Factory for client invoker.
java.io.IOException: Error initializing socket factory SSL context: Can not find truststore url.
        at org.jboss.remoting.security.SSLSocketBuilder.initializeSocketFactorySSLContext(SSLSocketBuilder.java:1340)
        at org.jboss.remoting.security.SSLSocketBuilder.createCustomSocketFactory(SSLSocketBuilder.java:451)
        at org.jboss.remoting.security.SSLSocketBuilder.createSSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketBuilder.java:431)
        at org.jboss.remoting.security.SSLSocketBuilder.createSSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketBuilder.java:381)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.ssl.HTTPSClientInvoker.createSocketFactory(HTTPSClientInvoker.java:140)
        at org.jboss.remoting.RemoteClientInvoker.<init>(RemoteClientInvoker.java:46)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.<init>(HTTPClientInvoker.java:105)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.https.TransportClientFactory.createClientInvoker(TransportClientFactory.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.jboss.remoting.InvokerRegistry.loadClientInvoker(InvokerRegistry.java:419)
        at org.jboss.remoting.InvokerRegistry.createClientInvoker(InvokerRegistry.java:320)
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.connect(Client.java:459)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.client.RemotingConnectionImpl.createRemotingClient(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:247)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.client.RemotingConnectionImpl.invoke(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:165)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.client.SOAPRemotingConnection.invoke(SOAPRemotingConnection.java:77)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPConnectionImpl.callInternal(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:106)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:66)
        at xxx.yyy.fooservice.FooServiceImpl.foo(FooServiceImpl.java:103)
        at xxx.yyy.fooservice.FooAsyncRunner.run(FooAsyncRunner.java:31)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
```

What can be I do to make these exceptions disappear? All help is highly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After a quick look at JBoss's [SSLSocketBuilder.loadTrustManagers](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/maven2/jboss.remoting/jboss-remoting/2.4.0.Beta2/org/jboss/remoting/security/SSLSocketBuilder.java), it tries to use the `org.jboss.remoting.trustStoreAlgorithm` property in the configuration, falling back to `org.jboss.remoting.keyStoreAlgorithm`, then falling back to the hard-coded default, `SunX509`.

Note that, even on a Sun/Oracle JRE, this is not the default value for the trust manager algorithm, [it's `PKIX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization).

I would report this as a bug/RFE to JBoss: it should probably fall back to [`TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/TrustManagerFactory.html#getDefaultAlgorithm%28%29) when nothing is set (that's the point of this method).

You may have to set one of these properties in the configuration explicitly to use IBM's default trust manager algorithm, to prevent it to fall back to these hard-coded default values.

Comment: I tried setting 

export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.jboss.remoting.trustStoreAlgorithm=IbmX509"
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.jboss.remoting.keyStoreAlgorithm=IbmX509"
... in jboss's startup.sh, but problem prevails - where should this config be specified if not there?

Comment: I doubt this is a system property (the way you've tried). Perhaps in a `something-service.xml`. Look at the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossremoting/docs/guide/2.5/html/chapter-configuration.htm

Comment: Wrong url in comment above (http://docs.jboss.org/jbossremoting/docs/guide/2.5/html/chapter-configuration.html), but as my other comment specified in http://pastebin.com/RW21nExF, I've even tried specifying it in jboss-service.xml... Thanks for the help, tho.

Answer (score 1):

With IBM JVM's the name is IbmX509 and not SunX509, which is the default value used by JBoss unless explicitly configured otherwise.

See http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/ssl-howto.html for details.  Search for IbmX509.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected "Sun" in there was an indication of what was wrong. But my web service code does not specify anything about HTTPS/SSL at all, so I'm very curious as to how to get the system running on AIX to use to correct classes. I've tried various settings for ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm=IbmX509 and
ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm=PKIX in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security, so a somewhat specific solution sugguestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I've also now tried specifying the config in server/default/jboss-service.xml (http://pastebin.com/RW21nExF), without any luck. How can I make this error disappear?

Comment: Sorry for not noticing your comments to my answer.  I do not know why I did not do so.